# Passing parameters to erb view

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I'm trying to pass parameters to an erb view using Ruby and Sinatra.

For example, I can do:

```
get '/hello/:name' do
  "Hello #{params[:name]}!"
end
```

How do I pass `:name` to the view?

```
get '/hello/:name' do
  erb :hello
end
```

And how do I read the parameters inside view/hello.erb?

Thanks!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

just pass the :locals to the erb() in your routes:

```
get '/hello/:name' do
    erb :hello, :locals => {:name => params[:name]}
end
```

and then just use it in the views/hello.erb:

```
Hello <%= name %>
```

(tested on sinatra 1.2.6)

Answer (score 18):

Not sure if this is the best way, but it worked:

```
get '/hello/:name' do
  @name = params[:name]
  erb :hello
end
```

Then, I can access `:name` in *hello.erb* using the variable `@name`

Comment: i couldn't get @name to work, but @@name worked (sinatra (1.3.2))

Comment: @name should work. https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra#accessing-variables-in-templates

Comment: I had the same issue. Restarting the app made it work.

Answer (score -7):

```
get '/hello/:name' do
  "Hello #{params[:name]}!"
end
```

You cannot do this in routes.

You want to set the params in the controller.

`app/controllers/some_controller.rb`

```
def index
    params[:name] = "Codeglot"
    params[:name] = "iPhone"    
    params[:name] = "Mac Book"      
end
```

`app/views/index.html.erb`

```
<%= params[:name] %>
<%= params[:phone] %>
<%= params[:computer] %>
```