# Pass variable between views (erb) using sinatra

Tags: sinatra

How can I pass a variable from one view to a partial view in Sinatra?

I already tried this:

**view1.erb**

```
<%= erb_partial :view2, locals: {test: "hello"} %>
```

**view2.erb**

```
<%= puts params[:test] %>
```

and also I tried:

**view1.erb**

```
<%=  erb_partial :view2, test: "hello" %>
```

There are [info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931942/pass-variable-between-views-in-rails) but for rails and for sinatra for sending one variable from controller to view, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737889/passing-parameters-to-erb-view), but  It did not help me unfortunately.

Any idea?

Comment: view files are on presentation layer and  doesn't contain a logic. the vairables are passed to them, they do not pass vairables. you can get querystring, or form variable etc. from a view file and also can pass it to another vew file. but inside of this process there should be a logic - in sinatra they are routes.  if you describe the situation totally, the more helpful solutions may be posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local variable is *passed* correctly to the partial view. So, in the partial view, it will be available as a normal local variable -- `test`. You should not use `params` to access them, the data it contains are different from the local variables available in a view.

So you should use it just like how you use a normal local variable :

**view2.erb**

```
<%= test %>
```